# RxJava 2 operator combination that delivers only the first Value from a bunch

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

The idea is when I call `publishSubject.onNext(someValue)` multiple times I need to get only one value like `debounce` operator does, but it delivers the last value, and I need to skip all values except first in a bunch till I stop calling `onNext()` for 1 sec.
I've tried to use something like `throttleFirst(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` but it's not working like debounce, it just makes windows after every delivery and after 1 sec immediate deliver next value.

Comment: Could post your example code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Observable<T> stream = ...;
stream.window(stream.debounce(1, TimeUnit.Seconds))
      .flatMap(w -> w.take(1));
```

**Explanation:** If I understand you correctly, you want to emit items if none have been emitted for 1 second prior. This is equivalent to getting the first element following an item debounced by 1 second. The below marble diagram may also help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first operator. Like:

```
Observable.first()
```

It will take only the first value